# How to copy the files from remote unix server to local windows?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I have my working system in a remote location and the os is in unix and i need to get the files from that remote unix system to my local machine using bash commands. I tried

```
scp ls .txt*  D:\BACKUP
```

this command by connecting using putty to my remote system.  i tried but its not working.

Comment: and how it's not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming that you have `scp` installed on your Windows (e.g. using Windows 10 bash)

The proper command is:

```
scp remote_username@remote_hostname.com:/full/path/to/file local_file_name
```

If you don't have `scp` installed on your windows you can install [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

You can use `winscp` to download using `sftp` ([see instructions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_connect))

> **Connecting**
>
> Start WinSCP. Login Dialog will appear. On the dialog:
>
> - Select your File protocol. When you are about to use FTPS protocol, select FTP and then choose one of the FTPS invocation methods.
> - Enter your host name to Host name field, username to User name and password to Password
> - Press Login to connect.

[image]